# Does Google fonts API v2 support ready to use Google's font effects?

Tags: css, webfonts, google-font-api

I am currently learning [Google fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started), and the current version as far as I know is version 2.

Applying fonts goes well but when I apply ready to use [font effects](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#enabling_font_effects_beta) it fails.

Here is the code that doesn't work (`effect=fire`).

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sofia&effect=fire');
```

And when I switch the API version from `css2` to `css` it works.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia&effect=fire');
```

I am using Chrome.

So the question is, does Google fonts API v2 support ready to use font effects? Or there is another way to get it done in v2?

What I have tried:

- Font effects working in earlier version.
- Font effects not working in version 2.

I read the following two offical links:

- [CSS API update](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2)
- [Get Started with the Google Fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started)

Comment: It explicitly says there that this is a “Beta” status feature, so I would not be surprised if it is not implemented across the board yet. And https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2#api_url_specification does _not_ list any `effect` parameter, so I would assume the answer is No, at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @CBroe. It make sense and your comment would also be the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with it too; but if you use css instead of css2 in the api link, things work; I have attached the working code for you.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sofia&effect=fire');
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chivo&effect=fire" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="font-effect-fire">This text is on fire<h1>
</body>
</html>
```